# Adding "retry" caused me to lose traceback

Tags: python, traceback

Currently I have a script defined like so:

```
import traceback
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=loggings.DEBUG)
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main_code()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        error = traceback.format_exc()
        with smtplib.SMTP("mailhub.global.company.com") as mailServer:
            msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
            msg['Subject'] = Header(u'Test', 'utf-8')
            msg['X-Priority'] = '2'
            body = "Delivery Failure, the following exception occurred:\n\n" + str(error)
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
            mailServer.sendmail("email@gmail.com", ["email@gmail.com"], msg.as_string()) 
            mailServer.quit()
        print("Exception occurred- delivery failure email sent")
```

This works perfectly in the sense that if there is an error, I receive an email with traceback.

I attempted to add a "retry" to the code in case of failure, so that it tries 5 times, with 5 seconds in between like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for attempt in range(5):
        try:
            main_code()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred, retrying in 5 seconds!")
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        error = traceback.format_exc()
        with smtplib.SMTP("mailhub.global.company.com") as mailServer:
            msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
            msg['Subject'] = Header(u'Test', 'utf-8')
            msg['X-Priority'] = '2'
            body = "Delivery Failure, the following exception occurred:\n\n" + str(error)
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
            mailServer.sendmail("email@gmail.com", ["email@gmail.com"], msg.as_string()) 
            mailServer.quit()
        print("Exception occurred- delivery failure email sent")
```

However, for some reason when I receive a delivery failure email now, all it says is: `Delivery Failure, the following exception occurred: NoneType: None`

Any idea how to bring back the traceback to the error in the email that is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is "cleaned up" (destroyed) when you leave the `except` block, so that functions in the `traceback` module cannot see it by the time you get to the final `else` block.  You probably want to move `error = traceback.format_exc()` into the `except` block (and also pass `error` to `logger.debug()`).

Comment: Thanks Kevin- do you mind providing a complete solution please? I tried adding error = traceback.format_exc() into the except block but that didn't seem to fix it

Comment: You need to *move* it, not add it.

Comment: Ah. Yup that was it. Thank you!